# Empty optional parameter will fall to home path

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

These are my routes:

```
import Search from './Search.vue'
import Home from './Home.vue'
export const routes = [
    {path : '/', name: 'Home', component: Home},
    {path : '/search/:keyword?', name: 'Search', component: Search}, //i put ? in the end of path to make this optional.
];
```

This is the action to route to the search page:

```
this.$router.push({
   name : 'Search',
   params : {
      keyword : this.keywords // set this to empty string
   },
   query: {
       page : 1
   }
})
```

If `this.keywords` is `''` (an empty string), it will go back to `gamedb.com/` (home). If there are some letters in `this.keywords`, the path will go to `gamedb.com/search/this-is-the-keyword`.

**My expected behavior is that when `this.keywords` is empty, the path will go to `gamedb.com/search`.**

My `console.log` shows this:

> [vue-router] missing param for named route "Search": Expected
>   "keyword" to match "[^/]+?", but received ""

Aren't I already putting a question mark at the end of the path of the route? Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that appending the question mark `?` to the param in the route path will make that param optional. But, this simply means that if you don't pass the `keyword` param at all, Vue Router won't complain.

You are passing a `keyword` param, but it is an empty string. URL params cannot be an empty string, so you are getting the error.

You need to add the `params` object to the options passed to `this.$router.push` only if the value of `this.keywords` is not empty:

```
this.$router.push({
  name : 'Search',
  params: (this.keywords.length > 0) ? { keyword: this.keywords } : {},
  query: {
    page : 1
  }
});
```